# Task dividing for a PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, scheduled-tasks, division

I have a website scraping script that is storing data into few MySQL tables. The records in the main table are referred from the other ones. The script would need around 5 hours to be executed, but it always stops working after around 70 minutes (set_time_limit() is set ofc). I tried to run it from both browser and cron, the result was the same.

Since the script stops at a random time, it can lead to database inconsistency. The main table record can be stored, but not the subordinant tables records using mysql_insert_id() from the main one.

Is there any better way than to delete the last record from the main table and all the referring records to the row from the other tables when running the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap all your queries for a given record in a transaction, and commit it at the end. That way, if the script dies partway through a set of queries, the changes will be rolled back and the data will be kept consistent.

Comment: Thanks. This method is the best.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: have you checked the TTL of the mysql connections? Maybe that's what's causing the problem?

If this problem keeps popping up, you might want to look at creating a db adapter object using PDO, You could simply start the script with: `$db->beginTransaction();` and end (if everything went smoothly) by committing the changes with `$db->commit();`.

There are many advantages to this approach, chief among which is the `$db->rollBack();` in case something goes wrong. Another advantage is, that when an error does occur MySQL-side, the PDO class throws a `PDOException` object, so you can do a rollback, to ensure no corrupt data is written to your db and exit in a way, similar to this `die($e->getMessage());` to see what exactly went wrong.

Check the [PDO man-page](http://www.php.net/PDO) for info

Comment: Do you mean mysql.connect_timeout? That is set to 60. Transactions look like thee best way to go.